# Pyspark - MetadataFetchFailedException when calculating tf - idf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce, rdd, spark-submit

I am working on a dataset of initially 569 MB, calculating the TF-IDF metric. Although I am getting results in the end I keep getting the below error:

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 84, X.X.X.X, executor 0): FetchFailed(null, shuffleId=4, mapId=-1, reduceId=4, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 4
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:878)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:878)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:691)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have read relative posts and have already changed some spark properties as below

```
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("part_2_task_2").config('spark.executor.memory','2g').config('spark.executor.memoryOverhead','1g').config('spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries',5).config('spark.shuffle.io.retryWait','30s').config('spark.network.timeout','200s').getOrCreate()
```

So currently I have the below cluster details:

```
spark.executor.cores    2
spark.executor.instances    2
spark.executor.memory   2g
spark.executor.memoryOverhead   1g
```

Moreover I checked in more details where the issue is from the UI and was able to find that the failed Stage arises from line 126 of my code which is the below join:

```
tfidf = tf.join(idf)
```

and the two rdds tf and idf are calculated as

```
tf = step1.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[0][1], x[0][2], x[0][3], x[1]/x[0][3])))
idf = step1.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[0][2], x[1], 1))). \
    map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][2])). \
    reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x +y ). \
    map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], math.log10(number_of_docs/x[1]))))
```

The rdds tf and idf have different `.count()` since `tf` is per each document and word whereas `idf` is per each word only thus I am joining them. Would that be an issue so I should check if they are equal size before joining by using partition commands although they are costly? If this is not an issue what would be the ideal cluster properties to process this kind of size data as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

I gave another 1g to the executor memory from the available 4G memory my virtual machine provides me so ended up in the following setting

```
spark.executor.memory   3g
spark.executor.memoryOverhead   1g
```

and the Exception disappeared.
I am not still sure if this is the best solution, or if my code needed fixing to overcome this issue of joining two rdds of different lengths, hence partitions that maybe have caused the problem. Any explanations would be much appreciated, since this is my first attempt with Apache Spark applications.